# Old answers in the Low Quality Posts review queue?

Tags: bug

I just had [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/10448/4207) pop up in the Low Quality Posts queue.  Any ideas on why an answer from a year and a half ago with 10 votes should be in there?

Comment: It got flagged by someone perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact algorithm, but I can vouch that its had 2 flags on it. One from a year ago (that got declined), and one yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Every so often someone will go through the old questions, or unanswered questions, and react to them like they'd react to any other set of questions.

If community standards or conduct has changed, then you'll see old posts that would pass current muster in the report or flag queues.